# How is the order of the array what Class.getConstructors() returns in Java

Tags: java, reflection

As we all know, Java reflection provides `Class.getConstructors` method, but how is the order of the `Constructor<?>[]` array?

For example, I create Person class and there are 3 construct method:

```
public Person()
{
}

public Person(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
}

public Person(int age, String name)
{
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}
```

And by debug, I find the order of constructor array like this:

```
0 = public xxx.Person(int)
1 = public xxx.Person(int, java.lang.String)
2 = public xxx.Person()
```

Comment: why is that important? what do you try?

Comment: This is not documented. Therefore there is no reliable answer. You can assume that it's just an arbitrary order.

Comment: When I look at the [Class#getDeclaredConstructors()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors()) I noticed the following line: "_The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order._" At the [Class#getConstructors()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors()) this isn't mentioned though. :S My assumption is that the same applies to that method, and your code also kind of proves that, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I am learning java Reflection, I try to use the return Constructor to make a new instance, like `Contructor.newInstance(Object... initargs)`

Comment: @BadEgg But when you use the `Constructor.newInstance(params)` you won't need to know the order of the constructors. Simply use the type and amount of parameters of the constructor your want to invoke, since all constructors have unique parameters.

Comment: @BadEgg I've made an edit to my [Answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34290127/1682559) with an example to call a specific Constructor with parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I look at the [Class#getDeclaredConstructors()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors()) I noticed the following line:

> "The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order."

At the [Class#getConstructors()-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors()) this isn't mentioned though..
Even though it isn't mentioned, my assumption is that the same applies to that method, which your code kind of proves.

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish (perhaps you could add you goal to your question so we might be able to help your further), but I don't think it's possible to get the Constructors in the same order using reflection.

---

EDIT: With the constructors in your example, you can call either of the three like this:

```
Class<Person> pClass = Person.class;
pClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // default constructor
pClass.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class).newInstance(50); // constructor with int parameter
pClass.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, String.class).newInstance(50, "test"); // constructor with int and String parameters
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I should not care about the order and the order is useless. But I can use `getDeclaredConstructor(Object... params)` to solve my problem. : )

Answer (score 1):

As constructor order does not matter for java classes there is not specification for getConstructors method order. I think testing you can figured out the default order, but I will not use it as can change any time. If you want to get an specific constructor check parameters or if the order does matter for you process the .java file as a simple text file.

[Java documentions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--).

> Returns an array containing Constructor objects reflecting all the
>   public constructors of the class represented by this Class object. An
>   array of length 0 is returned if the class has no public constructors,
>   or if the class is an array class, or if the class reflects a
>   primitive type or void. Note that while this method returns an array
>   of Constructor objects (that is an array of constructors from this
>   class), the return type of this method is Constructor[] and not
>   Constructor[] as might be expected. This less informative return
>   type is necessary since after being returned from this method, the
>   array could be modified to hold Constructor objects for different
>   classes, which would violate the type guarantees of Constructor[].
>   Returns:

Answer (score 0):

The `Class` class has several similar methods, such as `getInterfaces`, `getTypeParametrers`, `getMethods`, `getFields`, etc.

In most cases, when the order is well defined, it is specified in the javadoc. For example, [`getInterfaces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--):

> The order of the interface objects in the array corresponds to the order of the interface names in the implements clause of the declaration of the class represented by this object

The javadoc of `getConstructors` does not comment on order and **you should therefore not rely on the specific order you observed** as it may change across JVMs and possibly even from one run to another.

Answer (score 0):

The order is unspecified.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--) for the `Class.getConstructors()` method makes no mention of the order of the constructors.

That means that even if you can figure out what determines the order, you cannot rely on the order being the same across all JVM versions.

Interestingly, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) for the the `Class.getMethods()` method states *specifically* that you should not rely on the order of the methods returned.